# Lazy Loading on WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm building a WPF application, and I'm using a WebService to retrieve data from Database using Entity Framework.
On my service the code generated is:

```
public partial class DummyEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public DummyEntities() : base("name=DummyEntities", "DummyEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

//more 2 constructors with diferent signature but the same code
```

So the Lazy Loading option is enabled.

The problem is on the app side, when I do something like this:

```
DummyEntities context = new DummyEntities(Utils.GetUri());
//            ...
context.Order.Order_Details.Count
```

give me count = 0, when it shouldn't because Lazy loading is active. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Webservice and ef lazyloading not mix well

Comment: Have you considered WCF Data Services? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you've crossed a service boundary, the entities have been serialized and deserialized to another object, so they've lost the connection to the db

All lazy loading has to be done before the data is transferred

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint Daniel. I searched a little more and I found the LoadProprety method. That solves the problem.
Thanks

**Edit:**

The code I used was:

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = context.Order.AsEnumerable<Order>();

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            context.LoadProperty(order, "Order_Details");
            result.Add(new Order(order));
        }
```

This way I'm forcing each order to load the "Order_Details" related entity

Comment: Could you explain *how* it solved the problem? What did you change in order to get it to work?